# Process in idle mode

Tags: elixir

When a process is waiting to receive a message, it is idle and does not waste CPU time. What does that mean?

I have a recursive `loop` function:

```
def start do
    spawn(&loop/0)
end

defp loop do
    receive do
        {:run_query, caller, query_def} ->
            send(caller, {:query_result, run_query(query_def)})
    end

    loop
end
```

Is the CPU always busy with the process above or does it allow other processes to execute their tasks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is trivial to test, I fired up (similar) code on my laptop and observed the Process with ps:

```
$ ps -o %cpu,comm
 %CPU COMM
  0.0 /opt/boxen/homebrew/Cellar/erlang/18.0.3/lib/erlang/erts-7.0.3/bin/beam.smp
```

The process would be put into a sleep state by Beam (don't confuse process with operating system process, these are different things) and only woken up when a message is received.

Comment: What it does mean sleep, the process will be saved into memory until there get call?

Comment: In other words, it won't be using up unnecessary CPU cycles, and will allow other Erlang processes to run. The VM is smart enough not to waste time on a process that's not doing anything.

Comment: So when the Erlang VM plan to spawn new process, so the process get a small time window to execute or how it that works?

Comment: "The execution is suspended, possibly indefinitely, until a message arrives that matches one of the patterns and with a true guard sequence."

http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id80146

Comment: This is possibly implemented using [futex system calls](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/futex.2.html) or something similar

Answer (score 1):

what basically happens when you spawn new process VM will create new Erlang process and shove it into the queue and scheduler will run that process but if one of the process is not receiving any messages or not doing any computation its in idle state mean it won't get any time with cpu but the process still consume memory, a given process could be an several states there is even hibernate mode in which case the process is in sleep mode and the VM will claim the resources back and will wake up the process once there is message for that given process.